# Extending Wicket's serialization test

Tags: java, wicket, jpa-2.0

I'm working on a large Java application that uses Wicket 1.5 together with Hibernate / JPA 2. Wicket has a standard rule that objects stored in the session must implement `Serializable`. We have an extra rule that JPA managed objects must not be stored in the session. Instead, JPA managed objects are loaded on each request through detachable models.

To complicate matters, it is legitimate to store an Entity object in the session provided that it has not been persisted yet. As a result, some of our classes already implement `Serializable`.

If I wanted to extend Wicket's serialization test to detect objects owned by JPA, how would I go about it? Is this possible without a local fork of Wicket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At my $dayjob we use something what you describe, and what I have [presented at several meetups](http://www.slideshare.net/dashorst/keep-your-wicket-application-in-production) (see slide 23 and on). You don't have to fork Wicket for that.

Basically what you do is copy the serializer checker code and modify it to include your check as well as checking for serialization errors. Then in the last phase of the request cycle you run  your own serializer checker on the affected pages.

The check we created checks for our common base class, and wether or not the entity has ben persisted. If so, we fail the request. Additionally we have an Ajax callback in our base page that checks a session attribute to see if there was a serialization error. If so, we redirect to the error page with the serialization failure, to ensure that developers don't ignore the entity in page hierarchy.

Here's the meat of our checker (the `check` method rewritten from Wicket's serializer check):

```
private void check(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Deprecated.class)
        || obj.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(SkipClass.class))
    {
        return;
    }

    Class< ? > cls = obj.getClass();
    nameStack.add(simpleName);
    traceStack.add(new TraceSlot(obj, fieldDescription));

    if (!(obj instanceof Serializable) && (!Proxy.isProxyClass(cls)))
    {
        throw new WicketNotSerializableException(toPrettyPrintedStack(obj.getClass().getName())
            .toString(), exception);
    }
    if (obj instanceof IdObject)
    {
        Serializable id = ((IdObject) obj).getIdAsSerializable();
        if (id != null && !(id instanceof Long && ((Long) id) <= 0))
        {
            throw new WicketContainsEntityException(toPrettyPrintedStack(
                obj.getClass().getName()).toString(), exception);
        }
    }
    if (obj instanceof LoadableDetachableModel)
    {
        LoadableDetachableModel< ? > ldm = (LoadableDetachableModel< ? >) obj;
        if (ldm.isAttached())
        {
            throw new WicketContainsAttachedLDMException(toPrettyPrintedStack(
                obj.getClass().getName()).toString(), exception);
        }
    }
```

For Wicket 1.5 we created our own `PageStoreManager` that performs these checks (and a lot of other things, like enabling a server side browsing history for our users). We provided our own `RequestAdapter` by overriding `PageStoreManager#newRequestAdapter(IPageManagerContext context)` and doing the serialization check in the adapter:

```
class DetachCheckingRequestAdapter extends RequestAdapter
{
    public DetachCheckingRequestAdapter(IPageManagerContext context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void storeTouchedPages(List<IManageablePage> touchedPages)
    {
        super.storeTouchedPages(touchedPages);
        if (Application.get().usesDevelopmentConfig())
        {
            for (IManageablePage curPage : touchedPages)
            {
                if (!((Page) curPage).isErrorPage())
                    testDetachedObjects(curPage);
            }
        }
    }

    private void testDetachedObjects(final IManageablePage page)
    {
        try
        {
            NotSerializableException exception = new NotSerializableException();
            EntityAndSerializableChecker checker = new EntityAndSerializableChecker(exception);
            checker.writeObject(page);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.error("Couldn't test/serialize the Page: " + page + ", error: " + ex);
            Session.get().setDetachException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've implemented this in my application, and it works like a charm. It would be a little neater if Wicket had a convenient attachment point for session checks, but this is quite maintainable. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. You are free to submit a feature request. Unfortunately we can't make this a generic check, but being able to extend the framework in a more obvious way would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

For a simpler solution in Wicket 6.3.0+ see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Serialization+Checker

Answer (score 0):

A very easy approach is customizing serialization of your entities:

```
public Object writeReplace() throws ObjectStreamException {
  if (!isTransient()) {
    throw new NotSerializableException("persistent objects must not be serialized");
  }
  return this;
}
```

We've put this snippet into all of our entities (well, actually into a common base class called AbstractPersistentObject) and it works pretty well. The only thing it complicates is editing persistent entities or transient entities with persistent properties: you aren't allowed to serialize dirty/edited/modified objects.